# How to list/filter by the entry type column in the entries listing

Tags: entries, sorting

I've got a 'media' channel that has two entry types: Film and Report.

I have set the listing of entries to have the entry type column, but it doesn't seem to have any options for making it clickable to sort by entry type. Is this a current feature?

[image: Entry listing]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to sort by custom fields on element index pages.

Feel free to add a thumbs-up/comment on this feature request, though: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/987